# How To Get A Boolean Result From Search - SQLite Database

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Good day, I always used `getString()` and `getInt()` in getting results. I'm doing a simple searching and I want to get a boolean result if it is found.

Here's my sample code: **ForgotPassword.java**

```
 @Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    String strUserForget = edtForgotPassword.getText().toString().trim();

    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.buttonSubmit:

            if (strUserForget.matches("")){
                Toast.makeText(ForgotPasswordActivity.this, "Please Provide Complete Info", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else {
                //String forgetPassProject = "";
                Cursor cursor = (registerDatabase.getSingleRecordForgetPass(strUserForget));
                boolean value = (cursor.getInt(registerDatabase.ID) == 1);

                Toast.makeText(ForgotPasswordActivity.this, "Your password is: " , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            break;

        case R.id.buttonGoBackWelcome:
            startActivity( new Intent(getApplicationContext(),WelcomeActivity.class));
            finish();
            break;
    }

}
```

And for registerSQLDatabase.java

```
public Cursor getSingleRecordForgetPass(String username){

    String querySingleRecord = "SELECT * FROM " + DB_TABLE + "WHERE = " +FULL_NAME+ "LIKE" +username ;
    return  sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(querySingleRecord,null);
}
```

The boolean value = (cursor.getInt(registerDatabase.ID) > 0); is incompatible.

Comment: Are you getting cursor value more then 1 or not?

Comment: One only. For single item.

Comment: How do I make It right? I pass the "strUserForget" - (registerDatabase.getSingleRecordForgetPass(strUserForget));

Answer (score 1):

`boolean value = (cursor.getInt(registerDatabase.ID) == 1);` thows a [`NPE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) because it has no results, to avoid this Exception use `Objects.equals` and check number of results of the `Cursor`:

```
if (!Objects.equals(cursor, null) && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
    // has results
} else {
    // has NO results
}
```

Prior java 1.7:

```
if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
    // has results
} else {
    // has NO results
}
```

---

As a side problem, as [Rohit5k2](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2936153/rohit5k2) pointed there is an unnecessary `=` in your query:

```
String querySingleRecord = 
    "SELECT * FROM " + DB_TABLE + " WHERE " + FULL_NAME + " LIKE " + username ;
```

---

If you don't need `Cursor` information, just create a method that returns a boolean:

```
public boolean existsUser(String username)
{
    String querySingleRecord = "SELECT * FROM " + DB_TABLE + "WHERE " +FULL_NAME+ "LIKE" +username ;
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(querySingleRecord,null);

    // now you have the results, DON'T return them, just check if contains
    // > Java 7: if (!Objects.equals(cursor, null) && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
    if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

And use it in this way:

```
if (strUserForget.matches("")){
    Toast.makeText(ForgotPasswordActivity.this, "Username cannot be empty.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} else if (registerDatabase.existsUser(strUserForget)) {
    Toast.makeText(ForgotPasswordActivity.this, "Your password is: " , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} else {
    Toast.makeText(ForgotPasswordActivity.this, "User does not exists" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: My API is 15, what is the equivalent java code for "equals()" ?

Comment: Check my update, just use `cursor != null`

Comment: Thank You, I will try this one. - if(registerDatabase.existsUser(strUserForget) == true){
                        Toast.makeText(ForgotPasswordActivity.this, "User Exists " , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

Comment: `if(registerDatabase.existsUser(strUserForget) == true)` is the same than `if(registerDatabase.existsUser(strUserForget)){`

Comment: I got a nullpointerException. I just would to ask this line of code of mine - String querySingleRecord = "SELECT * FROM " + DB_TABLE + "WHERE = " +FULL_NAME+ "LIKE" +username ;
    return  sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(querySingleRecord,null);

This will return true right if found?

Comment: please, read carefully our answers and ask if you dont understand.... **BUT READ THEM PLEASE** as told several times `where =` is incorrect :(

Comment: I'm so sorry Sir Jordi.

Comment: I'm tracing my errors and apply your code. I truly appreciate your help. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105801/discussion-between-rock-and-jordi-castilla).